# How to run a react native project(android folder) in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

How can I run a react native project(android folder) in android studio? Is it possible?

[image: Getting the following error when click on run]

Answer (score 1):

open android folder using android studio and click run button on the top of that.
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Unable to load script. Make you're either running Metro

Comment: Run npx react-native start from the root folder of your project then run it from android studio